# Is there a way to see the amount of available disk space in php?

Tags: php, diskspace

Can I get the available disk space in php? Or can I somehow simply try to create a huge file (widthout it taking too much time to create) and see if it fits?

Comment: The function `disk_free_space()` (discussed in the answer below by Andrejs) is the first result for a Google search for `available disk space in php`. In general, you should try to solve the question yourself (i.e., do a little research) before asking a question here.

Comment: seriously... try the manual / google
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php

Comment: I did do a Google search. Strange I did not see that answer. I guess that I used different keywords. Sorry.

Comment: No... actually I did see that answer BUT. I need this information in a Joomla extension and I do not know what drive/path the site might be installed in. And the amount of physical space is not really relevant. It is the amount of physical space available on the hosting account that I need to know.

Answer (score 4):

[`disk_free_space`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.disk-free-space.php) — Returns available space on filesystem or disk partition

```
float disk_free_space ( string $directory )
```

Given a string containing a directory, this function will return the number of bytes available on the corresponding filesystem or disk partition.

**Example:**

```
<?php
// $df contains the number of bytes available on "/"
$df = disk_free_space("/");

// On Windows:
$df_c = disk_free_space("C:");
$df_d = disk_free_space("D:");
?>
```

Comment: That you for the answer. But I need to know the amount of space available on the hosting account (which I do not know the path to)

Comment: You might use the path to current script, `dirname(__FILE__)`. This should do the trick: `$df = disk_free_space(dirname(__FILE__))`.

Comment: Nope. Will not work as disk_free_space() does an open_basedir check which is disabled on almost all hosting accounts.

Comment: I have tested this on my Bluehost account, and it works. Since this is specific limitation to your hosting provider, I'd suggest you to contact your hosting support. I believe only they can give a 100% accurate answer on this. My answer is still correct.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs or `disk_free_space(__DIR__)`